# Web Security - How safe are url parameters?

Tags: security, web

I don't know much about web safety and I really am trying to learn. I apologize if this is a silly question.

If there were a request to my web site `/demo?name=Isaac`, would a hacker somehow be able to intercept the request and extrapolate that "Isaac" was passed as name? Of course, finding out someone's name isn't that big a deal. But would it be an awful idea to pass sensitive information as a URL parameter? Or is it safe?

Comment: Any data passed between a client and server can be intercepted, whether it's in the URL parameters, form data, cookies, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, files, etc. Especially if the data is not transmitted over HTTPS. Needless to say, sensitive stuff should only be over HTTPS.

Comment: @mason OK, I've actually found a safer alternate solution to what I was trying to do. But I'm still curious. Would it be difficult for a hacker to access the URL parameters if they are passed over HTTPS? Or would I for the most part be safe?

Comment: It's still generally a bad idea to put sensitive stuff in the URL parameters. If the person bookmarks the page, or forwards the URL to someone else, then that sensitive information would be included. Besides, your goal should be [friendly URL's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL).

Comment: Yea, I figured. I was updating the CSRF token (AJAX request login kept it from updating on the current page, causing the user to get logged out on the next request) by passing it as a URL parameter, and it just felt dirty, haha. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Not awful idea.
In HTTP protocol, how to pass data is only parameter.
If you want to send sensitive data to server, you have to use encrypted connection, like SSL/TSL.